# Getting dynamically generated textbox values MVVM

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I generate a couple of textboxes that are added to a stackpanel listbox item source

Now say e.g. 8 boxes generate with unique names, how do I retrieve the values from these objects?

This follow MVVM pattern so I can't directly call the xaml but need the values of the text boxes to save them

Comment: You can use two-way binding like this: `Text="{Binding SomeProperty, Mode=TwoWay}"`

Comment: Forgot to mention that I generate them dynamically, so the text boxes aren't on the xaml till the user clicks n generate button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create binding in the code-behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    // create and initialize textbox 
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();

    // bind Text to "SomeProperty" in your view model
    textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("SomeProperty") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay }) ;
}
```

You could alternatively use `ItemsControl` with `ItemTemplate` displaying `TextBox` and bound to a collection in view model. This way you would control number of text boxes by number of elements in the collection.